# Error in Adam Optimizer due to tf.assign function

Tags: tensorflow2.0

I have reproduced the error from my code. As shown in the code, combination of "input" and "loss_total" gives the error where gradients are None type. How can I resolve this.

```
grads_and_vars = optimizer_utils.filter_empty_gradients(grads_and_vars)
```

File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\keras\optimizers\optimizer_v2\utils.py:77 in filter_empty_gradients
raise ValueError(

ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable: (['Variable_541:0', 'Variable_542:0'],). Provided `grads_and_vars` is ((None, <tf.Variable 'Variable_541:0' shape=(5, 5) dtype=float32>), (None, <tf.Variable 'Variable_542:0' shape=(5, 5) dtype=float32>)).

## This function is used in the code.

def mean_squared_error(pred, exact):
if type(pred) is np.ndarray:
return np.mean(np.square(pred - exact))
else:
return tf.math.reduce_mean(tf.square(pred - exact))

class make_graph:

```
def __init__(self, ny, nx):

    self.R = 287
    self.u = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([ny+2, nx+2], tf.float32), trainable=True)
    self.v = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([ny+2, nx+2], tf.float32), trainable=True)

    
    self.U_padded = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([ny+2, nx+2], tf.float32), trainable=True)
    self.V_padded = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([ny+2, nx+2], tf.float32), trainable=True)

    
@tf.function
def loss_estimation(self):
    
    self.U_padded[1:-1,1:-1].assign(self.u)
    self.V_padded[1:-1,1:-1].assign(self.v)
    
    # self.loss_total = mean_squared_error(self.u-self.v+self.P-self.rho, 0) 
    
    self.loss_total = mean_squared_error(self.U_padded + self.V_padded, 0)
    
    return self.loss_total
    
    
@tf.function
def train(self, optimizer):
        with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
                           
            input = [self.u, self.v]
            # input = [self.U_padded, self.V_padded]
            
            self.loss = self.loss_estimation()
            
        self.gradients = tape.gradient(self.loss, input)
        optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(self.gradients, input))
```

if **name** == "**main**":

```
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate = 0.001)

model = make_graph(3, 3)

for i in range(10):
    model.train(optimizer)
    print(i)
```

Comment: Change this if name == "main": to if __name__ == "__main__":

Comment: I have the same issue, did you find how to solve it ?

Comment: Do not use tf.assign. It somehow break the graph (not completely sure). I changed m code to not use tf.assign in between the graph.